# Is it UB to access a non-existent object?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

There seems to be no more silly question than this. But does the standard allow it?

Consider:

```
void* p = operator new(sizeof(std::string));
*static_cast<std::string*>(p) = "string";
```

[[basic.life]/6](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6):

> Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated24 or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released... The program has undefined behavior if:
>
> - the pointer is used to access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the object, or
> - the pointer is used as the operand of a static_­cast ([expr.static.cast]), except when the conversion is to pointer to cv void, or to pointer to cv void and subsequently to pointer to cv char, cv unsigned char, or cv std​::​byte ([cstddef.syn]), or

(Note that according to [[intro.object]/10](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#10), a `std::string` object is not implicitly created by `operator new` because it is not of implicit-lifetime type.)

However, [basic.life]/6 does not apply to this code because there are no objects at all.

What am I missing?

Comment: that is not proper use of placement new operator.

Comment: @TheDreamsWind I know it is illegal. I just want a reason.

Comment: Uh, the code itself is wrong, you use placement new to construct a `std::size_t`, not a `std::string`

Comment: @Raildex No I allocated storage of `sizeof(std::string)` size with `operator new`.

Comment: This is defintely "before the lifetime has started" for a possible string and has a static_cast that is not to void.  How is that not UB?

Comment: @BoP Why is there a "possible string"?

Comment: To be able to assign to a `std::string`, one must first be created. The memory pointed to by `p` is large enough for that ("possible string"), but no string constructor has been invoked. So there is no string.

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#10.sentence-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[intro.object]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object)

> Some operations are described as implicitly creating objects within a specified region of storage. For each operation that is specified as implicitly creating objects, that operation implicitly creates and starts the lifetime of zero or more objects of implicit-lifetime types in its specified region of storage if doing so would result in the program having defined behavior. **If no such set of objects would give the program defined behavior, the behavior of the program is undefined**.

[[intro.object]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#11)

> Further, after implicitly creating objects within a specified region of storage, some operations are described as producing a pointer to a suitable created object. These operations select one of the implicitly-created objects whose address is the address of the start of the region of storage, and produce a pointer value that points to that object, if that value would result in the program having defined behavior. If no such pointer value would give the program defined behavior, the behavior of the program is undefined.

[[intro.object]/13](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#13.sentence-3)

> Any implicit or explicit invocation of a function named `operator new` or `operator new[]` implicitly creates objects in the returned region of storage and returns a pointer to a suitable created object.

If an `std::string[1]` (or `std::string[1][1]` etc.) object were created, and a pointer to the `std::string` subobject were produced by `operator new(sizeof(std::string))`, then `*static_cast<std::string*>(p) = "string"` would have undefined behavior per [basic.life]/(7.2)

> the glvalue [*denoting an out-of-lifetime object*] is used to call a non-static member function of the object

If `operator new(sizeof(std::string))` produced a pointer to object of some other type (like `int` or `double`), then undefined behavior would be triggered by [[expr.ref]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#8):

> If `E2` is a non-static member and the result of `E1` is an object whose type is not similar to the type of `E1`, the behavior is undefined.

So, there is no set of objects which would give the program defined behavior. Thus, the highlighted sentence of [intro.object]/10 apply here.

Comment: So, "Such operations do not start the lifetimes of subobjects of such objects that are not themselves of implicit-lifetime types" means that although the lifetime of the `std::string` object is not started, it is still created?

Comment: @Blackteahamburger I'm not sure if we say «created» about subobjects, but anyway, if a complete object of `std::string[1]` type is created, ofc  it has `std::string` array element.

Comment: It's rather strange... Maybe it's an oversight, I'll consider filing a defect report.

Comment: I don't get it. The only objects with implicit lifetime that [`void* operator new(std::size_t);`](https://eel.is/c++draft/new.delete#single-1) creates in this case are bytes.  Had the call in the question been followed by `auto sp = new(p) std::string; *sp = "string";`, surely that would have had defined behavior?

Comment: @TedLyngmo in this case `operator new(sizeof(std::string))` has UB. _Had the call in the question been followed by_ It would be a completely different story

Comment: @Blackteahamburger whats wrong with this? This was intentional to let users implement vector-like containers, where they (pretend that they) create an array `T[N]` and iterate over its elements, even if `T` is not an implicit-lifetime type.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Since the elements of such an array need to exist, how do they exist? I believe their lifetime won't and can't start, so they still need to explicitly create the elements of the array (and replace objects whose lifetime hasn't started and can't start...) to iterate over, so what's the point?

Comment: The implementation can choose not to implicitly create any objects, which doesn't seem to result in undefined behavior.

Comment: @Blackteahamburger _Since the elements of such an array need to exist, how do they exist?_ And how the answer to this should look like? They exist fine. They chill. Send you their best. _I believe their lifetime won't and can't start, so they still need to explicitly create the elements of the array to iterate over_ It is possible to point at objects outside lifetime, they are still array elements, so there is no problem with iterating over them.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer So why does someone need that kind of iteration? What is the use of such iteration?

Comment: @Blackteahamburger If, say, someone writes `data() + size()` (where `size()` is 0), `data()` is better to point at object of type `T`. (for a vector with `T`s)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer In this case, is there no need to implicitly create an array?

Comment: @Blackteahamburger why?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer In this case, `data() + size()` is a pointer to the first byte of uninitialized storage. If an array is created, it is a pointer to the first uninitialized element. There's not much difference.

Comment: @Blackteahamburger  _In this case, `data() + size()` is a pointer to the first byte of uninitialized storage_ Such pointer value does not exist. And pointer arithmetic is defined for pointers to objects and past them (also, null pointer values, but only if adding 0)

Answer (score 1):

`static_cast` is fine, however dereferencing resulting pointer to (non-existing) `std::string` object leads to Undefined Behaviour:

> **7.2.1 Value category [basic.lval]**
> **11** If a program attempts to access (3.1) the stored value of an object through a glvalue whose type is not similar (7.3.5) to one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
> (11.1) the dynamic type of the object,
> (11.2) a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object, or
> (11.3) a char, unsigned char, or std::byte type.
> ...

Edit:

Quote from the question is not really applicable here, it  refers to a situations like this:

```
struct foo
{
    bar b1;
    bar b2;

    foo(void): b1{&b2}, b2{} {}
};
```

Comment: One problem with this is that `p` points at no object at all, so we cannot even start talking about the type of the object being accessed

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. The important part is that the type of the object being accessed is not `std::string`.

Comment: @user7860670 But no objects exist.

Comment: @Blackteahamburger Yes, and this is the problem. In order for `static_cast<std::string*>(p)` dereference to be valid `p` needs to really point at the valid object of `str::string` type.

Comment: _The important part is that the type of the object being accessed is not `std::string`_ Any program accessing an `std::string` object will have undefined behavior.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. _p points at no object at all_ Impossible situation. At least, not true for the OP code

Comment: @LanguageLawyer what type of object does it point to? How is that object created? See https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. _what type of object does it point to? How is that object created?_ When undefined behavior is triggered by `operator new(sizeof(std::string))`, these questions just do not arise.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer this by itself does not have UB. If you mean that a suitably completed program has UB, then yes, it does. It is however a bit difficult to explain why a program has UB, if for every sentence you get a remark that this sentence is meaningless because the program has UB. We must somehow consider fragments that are OK by themselves.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. _this by itself does not have UB_ It does, see https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I don't see any hint anywhere. Please point out a specific paragraph.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#10.sentence-3

Comment: @LanguageLawyer no. An empty set is a set. An empty set of objects gives this statement, suitably completed to a program, defined behaviour. (And other sets do that too).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Ofc, you can arbitrarily complete `operator new(sizeof(std::string))` to a program so that it has defined behavior from this paragraph POV. But https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#10.sentence-3 is not about implicitly creating objects operations which are arbitrarily completed to a program, it is about operations in a specific programs, such as OPs one (suitably completed), where `operator new(sizeof(std::string))` itself has undefined behavior.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer  Statements by themselves cannot have UB, only complete programs. See my comment above on reasoning about programs with UB.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. _Statements by themselves cannot have UB, only complete programs_ Ye, ye, and UB is also retroactive in time etc. Also, programs do not have UB at all, «undefined behavior» is about behavior of an implementation executing the program (http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.compliance.general#2.sentence-1). See, I also can into empty talks. Maybe even better than you. But the point is simple: `operator new` is specified as an operation implicitly creating objects and if such operation can not invent suitable set of objects, it has undefined behavior…

Comment: … so you just do not «reach» the state when you can discuss a pointer value

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Maybe, I don't know. I'm on vacation and I have maxed out my quota of language lawyering for today.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Why are you claiming that `operator new` in this case can not invent suitable set of objects? Why usual pack of unsigned chars won't be fine in this case?

Comment: Because using an object expression of type `std::string` which denotes `unsigned char` object (or array of `unsigned char` etc. if you also suggest that a pointer to such an object is returned by `operator new`) to call `std::string::operator=` is UB (http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#8.sentence-1)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Why would even bring this up? With such a bogus logic `operator new(sizeof(std::string))` may as well lead to UB when a couple of lines later program contains a division by zero which does not even use the result of allocation.

Comment: _Why would even bring this up?_ Because invocation of `operator new` is an operation which implicitly creates objects (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.object#13.sentence-3), so https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.object#10 (and /11) apply. _With such a bogus logic …_ Why is it bogus?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.object#13.sentence-3 and https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.object#10 make `void* p = operator new(sizeof(std::string));` well-defined. *"If no such set of objects would give the program defined behavior, the behavior of the program is undefined."* does not mean that you can temporary assume that it is well-defined to proceed program  execution to the next line and then somehow rollback execution and judge that behavior of `operator new`  invocation was actually undefined.

Comment: If the program ended at `void* p = operator new(sizeof(std::string));` (e.g. this were the last line before `}` in the main function), then sure, the behavior would be defined. _... does not mean ..._ It does mean something like this, read the proposal which added the wording

Answer (score 0):

> Is it legal to access a non-existent object?

No, you wrote it yourself:

> The program has undefined behavior if:
> the pointer is used to access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the object

which is exactly what `*static_cast<std::string*>(p) = "string";` does. You must construct a `std::string` before you call the assignment operator:

```cpp
int main() {
    void* p = operator new(sizeof(std::string));
    std::string* sp = new(p) std::string;        // construct the string
    
    *sp = "string";                              // now assignment is fine
    
    sp->~basic_string();
    operator delete(p);
}
```

> However, `[basic.life]/6` does not apply to this code because there are no objects at all.

Yes it's applicable here. Your code has allocated the storage but not started the lifetime of the object and calls a non-`static` member function of the (non-existing) object.

---

The confusion seems to stem from the fact that you never start the lifetime of the object and you therefore think that "before the lifetime" doesn't apply. It does. It's "before the lifetime" until you start the lifetime. If you never start the lifetime of the object, it's "before the timetime" during the complete program run.

The standard clause could have said: The program has undefined behavior if the pointer is used to access a non-`static` data member or call a non-`static` member function of the object if the object's lifetime has not been started - and it would mean the same thing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248227/discussion-on-answer-by-ted-lyngmo-is-it-ub-to-access-a-non-existent-object).

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is undefined by omission.

The assignment operator is overloaded, so a member function named `operator=` is invoked. The standard says

> A non-static member function may be called for an object of its class type

There isn't any object of an appropriate type, and there is nothing else in the standard that might be giving meaning to this program.

Comment: What about `static_cast<std::string*>(p)`?

Comment: The cast by itself is OK.

Comment: _The behaviour is undefined by omission._ I think the standard is pretty explicit